# "Flatten" vector image in Illustrator so that invisible objects are not included

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, flatten

I have multiple objects on top of each other in various layers.
Now I would like to export a version of my file where only the visible parts of all the objects and layers will be included.
How do I proceed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "visible parts"? Are they inside clipping masks? Opacity masks? Are they transparent? Something else?

Comment: I meant objects, which are partly covered by other objects. So that in the new file only the parts of the covered objects be included, which are not covered by any other object.

Comment: Its slightly tedious but possible... Also it will not work if you have any pixel images or effects in the file.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, the answer depends on what you're working with; there's no one button catch all solution. [How do I flatten this vector logo leaving only the visible black paths?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79965/how-do-i-flatten-this-vector-logo-leaving-only-the-visible-black-paths) will help if you're working with a limited number of colors (or some other selectable attribute) or objects.

Comment: Also it will most likely drive your file size up quite much.

Comment: Are you trying to "export" to another Illustrator file? Because otherwise, wouldn't exporting to a JPG achieve what you are trying to do? You could also try exporting to a PDF. I think that will retain the layers if you reopen the PDF in illustrator.

Comment: .. ... Pathfinder...... Merge..... http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind/28129#28129

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (only works with vector)

Select all your vectors, go to Object>>Flatten transparency. This will make all vectors closed, so the outlines.

Pathfinder>>trim.

This wil make a top object cut all the objects behind it and so on.

See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that unless all of your objects are stroked, you may end up with the same problem as [in this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65058/18306)

Comment: That is what @tzippy wants. I do not know what is that for. I just answered.

Comment: I dont think you can draw that conclusion. People often have all kinds of ideas untill they realize the consequences of those ideas. Which is probably why this has been left unanswered, rightfully so. Note that this does not work on all vector scenes, it fails to work on  transparency and gradient meshes for example