# Converting complex layered vectors into coloring pages

Tags: shapes

[image]I have a series of images that were created for me by a visual designer. They are beautifully done, but consisted of layered shapes that do NOT have outlines. I would like to make coloring pages from these but because of all the layering I can't just select all, fill white and add a stroke. I have tried rasterizing and doing an image trace but I can't figure out settings that do this fairly cleanly. It seems illustrator doesn't do a great job at tracing former vector images, how ironic. Any ideas here would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christine

[image: example of image I would like to create a coloring page for]

Comment: Hit F7 and CTRL+Y and post a screenshot so we can have all the facts here.

Comment: Flatten transparency + pathfinder trim - cleans it up quite a bit!

Answer (score 2):

This post actually works really well for this in case anyone is interested.You'll still need to do clean up, but it is greatly minimized.

["Flatten" vector image in Illustrator so that invisible objects are not included](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83178/flatten-vector-image-in-illustrator-so-that-invisible-objects-are-not-included)

This is the image after flattening transparency and using pathfinder > trim.

[image]

Finally, here is the completed image, after merging some of the stray objects. Only took a few minutes.

[image]